# The best way to allocate a hostname for multiple ec-2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to develop an autoscaling policy with Cloud formation template to spinup multiple ec2-instances when my load surge happens in AWS cloud.

Every time the new nodes gets generated via autoscaling ;I need to allocate a hostname. The hostname should be in such a way that  it should resemble the nodes application role ( such as web,db,or mail server  etc....This is a requirement of my legacy application.The host name can be in sequence like web01,web02 for web servers and db01,db02... for db server .I am not sure how i can achieve it ,Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Side-question: Why do you need the hostname? Typically, auto-scaled instances are used behind a Load Balancer, or each instance pulls work from a queue. There should be no need to direct traffic or connect to a specific instance, hence no particular need for a hostname.

Comment: I have some legacy applications which needs a host name.We are migrating some of legacy applications to cloud.

Comment: where do you need the hostname? On the instance itself or do you need to know it anywhere outside?

Comment: What do you mean by `host-role`? What is host? What is role? Won't all instances have the same role? How is your legacy system going to be informed when hosts are added/removed? Feel free to Edit your Question to add more details.

Comment: @John Rotenstein  Thanks for your suggestions, I added more details in the question.My legacy system is physical servers created by kickstart servers ,and I am planning an application migration  to cloud.

Comment: If you have 3 instances and #2 is terminated, and a new instance is added, what number do you want to give it Would it become web02 or web04? Is it okay to skip numbers, as long as they are unique?

Comment: It is better we can allocate web02, but  web04 is also work

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a one-liner:

```
 sudo hostname `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info | jq -r .InstanceProfileArn | cut -d "/" -f 2`
```

Just run this at instance startup (in `cloud-init` script, in `/etc/rc.local`, in `/etc/init.d/hostname` etc.).

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/info` receives information in JSON format about IAM instance profile (EC2 instances don't really have IAM roles, they have profiles derived from IAM roles).

`jq -r .InstanceProfileArn` extracts only profile ARN from that JSON.

`cut -d "/" -f 2` removes everything from profile ARN except the last part, which matches IAM role.

`hostname`... Well, sets the hostname.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey Kovalev. But this will not solve my problem.I want to add multiple hostnames in sequence as part of autoscaling  with a Cloud formation template.I have added more details by editing the question.